# How can I use abcde to rip to mp3 and embed album art under Trusty and Xenial?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, mp3, abcde

I would like to use the commandline audio ripper abcde to:

1. Rip audio cds to mp3
2. Download *and* then embed the appropriate album art

Can someone show me an example of how to accomplish this under *both* Trusty Tahr LTS and Xenial Xerus LTS?

*Full disclosure: I was formerly one of the maintainers of [abcde](https://abcde.einval.com/wiki/).*

Comment: I came across this that worked real well!
http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/abcde/getalbumart.html#embedmp3

Comment: This is my work :)

Comment: FTR you can split an mp3 album with `mp3splt -s -p th=-50,nt=10 album.mp3, where _`th`: threshold level (dB) to be considered silence_ and _`nt` number of tracks_.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For both Trusty and Xenial it is a good idea to use one of the multimedia PPAs of mc3man to get the *most modern* abcde available:

**1. Installation for Trusty:**

Add the following PPA and some required packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install abcde lame eyed3 glyrc imagemagick cdparanoia
```

**2. Installation for Xenial:**

Add the following PPA and some required packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install abcde lame eyed3 glyrc imagemagick cdparanoia
```

**3. Running abcde for Trusty or Xenial:**

You can use a customised `~/.abcde.conf` file to get quality mp3 files as well as album art but if you just want to use the commandline simply use the following, under either Trusty or Xenial:

```
abcde -o mp3:-V2 -a default,getalbumart
```

This will find the album art and download it next to your mp3 files which will be encoded to Variable Bitrate with bitrate averaging between 170-210 kbps. What more could you want?

**4. Embed the album art?**

Well, you could want to actually *embed* the cover image into your mp3 files. To do this simply change to the directory that holds your mp3s and the cover image and run the following:

```
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 --add-image cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER "$i"
done
```

And *now* you are done :)

**References:**

- [Hydrogen Audio: Lame recommended Settings](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME)

Comment: Note that for Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, that's `add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/bionic-media`